# Unable to have persistent Session ID -- NodeJS, Express, React

Tags: node.js, session, redis, cors, express-session

A front end on React where when I reach the landing page, there is a START button which is only triggered the one time when clicked and hits the `/start` endpoint.
Rest subsequent requests from front end go to the `/upload-audio` endpoint.
The session ID does not change with subsequent requests coming from front end.
Everything seems to be working fine when running on localhost (without Redis memory store)

The moment I introduce Redis and deploy the front end (on Vercel) and back end on (on Render), the session ID changes between subsequent requests from the same session. Basically the /start endpoint sends a session ID to server that changes after the subsequent request to /upload-audio. I am using Redis as an in-memory store to keep session ID persistent.

(I did change the CORS and endpoints from localhost when deploying on cloud)

Been debugging from 2 days but cant find a solution that works.

**Please help !!**

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
require('dotenv').config();
const session = require('express-session');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis').default;

const { createClient: createRedisClient } = require('redis');

const redisClient = createRedisClient({
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
  socket: {
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
  },
});

try {
  redisClient.connect();
  console.log('Redis client connected successfully');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error connecting to Redis:', error);
}

// Initialize store.
const redisSessionStore = new RedisStore({
  client: redisClient,
  prefix: 'session:',
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true }));

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'suresh',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    rolling: true,
    store: redisSessionStore,
    cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: 600000, sameSite: 'none', httpOnly: false },
  })
);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/start-ai', async (req, res) => {
  const sessionId = req.sessionID;
  console.log('Session ID is: %s', sessionId);

  // Run Functions and store as const firstMessage 

    return res.status(200).send(firstMessage);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

app.post('/upload-audio', upload.single('audio'), async (req, res) => {
  const sessionId = req.sessionID;
  console.log('Session ID for audio: %s', sessionId);

  //* Get audio file in API request
  try {
    const audioFile = req.file;
    if (!audioFile) {
      return res.status(400).send('No audio file uploaded.');
    }

    // Run transcription on Audio file and other functions

    return res.status(200).send({ lastMessage, chatStatus: true });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting response:', error);
    return res.status(500).send('Error processing audio');
  }
});
```

Comment: Browsers do not allow an insecure origin like `http://localhost:3000` to set cookies marked `Secure`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try to save session data where you create the session. Session.save() method is used to save session data between requests. For instance:**

```
app.post("/createSession", async (req, res) => {
       const username = req.body.username;
       const password = req.body.password;
       const user = {username: username, password: password);
       req.session.user = user;
      
       req.session.save((err) => {
           if (!err) {
              res.json({session_data: req.session.user});
          }
           else {
              console.error("Error: " + err);
         }
    });
});
```